# Scroll view not functioning after adding custom controls

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, custom-view, disabled-control

I am developing an app where i click a button and a bunch of controls (custom view) add at the bottom of the screen. I can click the button as many times as i want. So i end up adding controls at the bottom. I want to scroll up and count how many i added. Suppose i intended to add the custom view 5 times. I added 4.Scroll up count how many i added. I added 4, so scroll down, add 1 more and scroll up and save/do some calculation. But i am unable to scroll up after adding the custom controls. The screen shows the most recently added custom view and stays there. I cannot scroll up to check how many times i have added. What am i doing wrong.?Any ideas? So first time i click to add custom view, this code executes

```
ITMCustomView *customView = [[ITMCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake(187, 560, 400, 400)];
customView.delegate = self;
[self.scrollView addSubview:customView];
```

The custom view itself has a "Add More" button. If i click that then the above action should perform ,adding the custom control again. So i do this on "Add More"

```
[self.delegate addNewSize:CGRectMake(187,self.y+ 400 , 400, 400)];
```

What i am doing is passing the new location where the new custom view has to be created. So that delegate launches this method

```
- (void)addNewSize:(CGRect)frame
{
    ITMCustomView *cView = [[ITMCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    cView.delegate =self;
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, (frame.origin.y/500)*400);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:cView];
}
```

This is actually a continuation of my question [Add a bunch of controls dynamically to screen in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846736/add-a-bunch-of-controls-dynamically-to-screen-in-ios)
But i accepted answer (which is true answer for that question) and since its an extension wanted to start a new question. If you need more information please ask.Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `setContentSize` after adding your `ITMCustomView`. like

`[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];`

you've to set your `scrollView`  `contentSize` dyncamically, each time whenever you are adding your `custom view`.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at some info on web and i came across the same concept. Also this helped me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944294/how-i-auto-size-a-uiscrollview-to-fit-the-content